Phrasing an instruction involving the "for all" quantifier
I did a number theory course where the instructor sometimes phrased an exercise in a way that seems slightly wrong. For example, he wrote the exercise

Check if the following statement is correct: for every positive
integer $n$ we have that $q=p_1p_2\cdots p_n+1$ is prime where $p_n$ is
the $n$th prime.

as

For every positive integer $n$ let $q=p_1p_2\cdots p_n+1$ where $p_n$
is the $n$th prime, check if the following statement is correct: "$q$
is prime."

The way that he phrased the exercise is clear enough, but just seems weird, and I want to know if this style is common. I'm not asking for a solution to this problem, just whether this type of phrasing is normal?
More generally, can a question of the form "is it true that for every $x\in A$ we have $P(x)$?" be rephrased as "for every $x\in A$ is it true that $P(x)?$"?
Note: this is a question about mathematical writing, not about the logic of quantifiers.

I think it's not great phrasing because $q$ isn't a number, it's a function  of $n$ even if you leave the $n$ out of the notation.  Better to call it $q_n$ and then ask whether $q_n$ is prime for all natural numbers $n$ or not.  But, as you say, it's perfectly clear what is intended.

I honestly don't understand the problem with the phrasing. It seems clear that $q$ is different for each $n$.

Or just leave $q$ out of the question.   Something like "Where $p_k$ denotes the $k$-th prime, then for every positive integer $n$ , check whether $p_1p_2⋯p_n+1$ is prime."

Note that $2\times3\times5\times7\times11\times13+1=59\times509$.

If you take the second version too literally, it's saying "check whether $q$ is prime when $n=1$, and check whether $q$ is prime when $n=2$, and ...". The only valid (finite) answer to that would be some sort of formula or algorithm, if even that's acceptable.

I endorse @aschepler's comment 110%. The second version is a much harder problem than the first. See my answer for more details. I don't think mathematics educators should be using shoddy wording as it is likely to destroy confidence in our science.

I think your professor's wording is weird to the point of absurdity as it's asking you to do something much harder than what he or she intends. "For each <$x$> in some infinite sequence $x_1, x_2, \ldots, $ check if $\phi(x)$ holds" is a command to carry out an infinite number of checks. It's asking a different question from "check whether $\phi(x)$ holds for all $x$ in $x_1, x_2, \ldots$".
In the specific case in question, the answer to "check whether $x$ is prime holds for all $x$ in $p_1 + 1, p_1p_2 + 1, \ldots$" is fairly easy: it's false, as has been stated in a comment because $2\cdot 3\cdot \cdots \cdot 13$ is not prime. However, the answer to "for all $x$ in $p_1 + 1, p_1p_2 + 1, \ldots$ check whether $x$ is prime", should enumerate all the counter-examples not just one. (I don't know, but I'd be surprised if there was a known answer to this that lists all such $x$ in a useful way. I suspect you can show that the list is infinite, but I'm not sure about that.)

I don't think its weird! you have to find only one counterexample to statee it is not true for all n.

@trula: but the second wording as quoted in the question doesn't say that.

I see the "for every n" in both wordings.

You should look at the bit that says "check ...". Being told to check a property for every value in some set is quite different from being told to check whether that property holds for every value in that set: the former requires every value to be checked, while the latter can be determined as false as soon as a counter-example has been found.


More generally, can a question of the form "is it true that for every $x\in A$ we have $P(x)$?" be rephrased as "for every $x\in A$ is it true that $P(x)?$"?

Although the second phrasing is actually asking multiple questions, it is reasonable to treat the two phrasings as equivalent.


for every positive
integer $n$ we have that $q=p_1p_2\cdots p_n+1$ is prime where $p_n$ is
the $n$th prime.


Side note: here, ‘where’ means if rather than and, and I'm inclined to rewrite the sentence in either of these ways:

For every positive integer $n,$ if for every positive integer $k,\,p_k$ denotes the $k$th prime, then $p_1p_2\cdots p_n+1$ is prime
$\forall n\, \big(\left(\forall k\, A(k)\right)\implies B(n)\big)$

If for every positive integer $k,\,p_k$ denotes the $k$th prime, then for every positive integer $n,\,p_1p_2\cdots p_n+1$ is prime
$\left(\forall k\, A(k)\right)\implies \forall n\, B(n).$



I disagree that the professor's phrasing can be reasonably read in the way you suggest. "Check" here is a command to the student, not a logical statement and the answer to the question in that form would be quite different.

@RobArthan Your comment totally isn't a meaningful response to my answer. Firstly, see that I was addressing the OP's general question (not the OP's professor's shoddy instructions), then suggesting how to improve the given mathematical statement — neither of which involves the instruction/word "check". Secondly, notice that my answer above begins by pointing out that the second phrasing—unlike the first—is asking infinitely many questions, and that the entirety of your just-posted answer is elaborating on this point.

@RobArthan To belabour the facts: yes, the two queries proffered by the OP in their general question are reasonably treated as equivalent, and yes, the professor's particular instruction for their student to (literally) carry out infinitely many checks is not a reasonable way to do the given exercise.


More generally, can a question of the form "is it true that for every $x∈A$
we have $P(x)$?" be phrased as "for every $x∈A$ is it true that P(x)?" ?

Yes, it may be phrased either way without changing how you answer the question.
